# How do I list all installed NuGet packages?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, nuget, command-line-interface

How does one list all locally installed NuGet packages?

Is there a NuGet equivalent of `RPM -qa`? Within [Chocolatey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NuGet#Chocolatey) there is the `chocolatey list -localonly`, but for the life of me I cannot find the NuGet equivalent of that command.

Answer (score 137):

In the *NuGet Package Manager Console*, enter the following command:

```
Get-Package | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

This will either print out a list of installed packages, or if none are present write the following line to the console:

```
PM> Get-Package
No packages installed.
```

For more details, have a look at the [NuGet PowerShell Reference](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/Reference/Package-Manager-Console-PowerShell-Reference#Get-Package).

Comment: Is there a way to do this using nuget.exe?

Comment: After running the command `Get-Package`, [packages' names are trimmed](http://imgur.com/a/f6Vjs) when they have more than 32 characteres. Is it possible to increase the package name column so that the output show the full names without trimming them?

Comment: `Get-Package | Format-Table -AutoSize` will do it

Answer (score 72):

If you just do

```
Get-Package
```

it will list the packages and where they are referenced. It will list the same packages over and over again if you have them referenced many times. If you want to get a clean list of all packages installed in the solution you can do

```
Get-Package | select -Unique Id, Versions
```

Comment: To sort:
`Get-Package | select -Unique Id, Versions | sort Id

Answer (score 20):

If you have the .NET Core runtime installed, you can use the [dotnet list package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-list-package) command in the .NET Core CLI tools to fetch installed packages for a given solution or project. Use it like so from the Windows command line:

```
dotnet list "C:\Source\MySolution\MySolution.sln" package
```

It works on both .NET Framework and .NET Core projects.

**Note:** For this command to work, the solution must use the [new NuGet PackageReference format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference) for referencing NuGet packages. Migration is as easy as right-clicking packages.config, and clicking "Migrate packages.config to PackageReference...", then restoring packages by building the solution.

Comment: Does work for .NET Core but not for .NET 4.5 Solution: At least this is the case on my computer.

Comment: @ChristianCasutt I just tested it and it works just fine on .NET Framework 4.5, the only thing I had to do was [migrate from packages.config to PackageReference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference), and then restore nuget packages by building the solution.

Comment: Isn't there a difference between referencing/use and installed? Aren't NuGet packages installed globally, independent of solutions/projects?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I'm assuming here that the OP meant installed for a project/solution. Globally the downloaded packages are cached, and I don't think the term "installed" would make sense in that context.

Answer (score 17):

```
Get-Package -ProjectName "Your.Project.Name"
```

Will show the packages for the specified project.

See also: [Package Manager Console PowerShell Reference](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-manager-console-powershell-reference)

Note that each project will have a packages.config file which is used to track installed packages. If this is altered (specifically if you alter it backwards), the projects may not automatically download the correct package version. In that case, make a note of the packages required and do a uninstall-package, followed by a install-package for each.

Also, backups are your friend! ;)

Answer (score 14):

In Visual Studio,

- go to the **Project** or **Solution** in question
- right click, *Manage NuGet Packages*...
- on the left, you will see '*Installed Packages*'
- click on this and you will see the list

Answer (score 12):

In addition to all of the given answers, there is also a clean listing in XML format of all installed packages in your Visual Studio project root folder: *packages.config*:

[image]

Comment: In my opinion, the best response.

Comment: With the new project file structure introduced in Visual Studio 2017 version 15.7 NuGet packages can (or will for new projects) be moved to the project file, and you won't find a `packages.config` file. See [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference).

Comment: This only gives you one project at a time though. I have about 250 projects in my solution so other answers are better if you don't want to go through the solutions one at a time.

Comment: For newer solutions, changes are high that you do not have a packages.config file, but instead PackageReference inside project file or even in lock files. There are now several ways to list up nuget packages !

Answer (score 9):

Answer to ["Is there a way to do this using nuget.exe? – bitbonk"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22363960/how-to-list-all-installed-nuget-packages#comment69716498_22364258):

```
nuget list -Source C:/packages
```

Where C:/packages is a path to your local repository.

Comment: Note that I had to use an absolute path for this to work.

Comment: Per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/cli-reference/cli-ref-list (and as noted by Peter Mortensen in another comment below), this lists all available packages for the `-Source`. It does not list the *installed* packages.

Answer (score 7):

> How do I list all installed NuGet Packages?

Assuming that [NuGet is properly installed](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/installing-nuget)

Right click **Project** node and click **Manage NuGet Packages**

[image: Right click Project node]

See **installed packages list**

[image: See installed packages]

Answer (score 2):

Answer to "Is there a way to do this using nuget.exe?" – [bitbonk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4227/bitbonk)

Based on the answer from [jstar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4182401/jstar) above. I used `\` instead of `/` which fits more to the Windows environment where nuget is at home. My edit of the answer was rejected so I post my own.

`nuget list -Source c:\code\packages`

Where `c:\code` is a path to your local code-repository.
The `packages` folder is on the same level like your solution-file (*.sln).

Comment: But this lists the sources (where the packages come from), not the *installed packages* (?).