# Get all references of C# projects

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, nuget-package, projects-and-solutions

For a given project, I want to get all references to assembly locations (assembly references, Nuget Package references and its nested references, Project references and its nested references).

Is there a way to do all of this? I don't want to exploit projects.assets.json file witch contains all informations about package references. And I also looked in the directory specified by the OutputPath property in the project file but I didn't find all assemblies.

Comment: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/458362/how-do-i-list-all-loaded-assemblies)  and [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383686/how-do-you-loop-through-currently-loaded-assemblies)

Comment: might this will help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/598129/dependency-graph-of-visual-studio-projects

Comment: In addition to the above - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22363960/how-to-list-all-installed-nuget-packages/39994517